# Ensure a function parameter is a key of an interface AND that the interface entry type is a number

Tags: typescript

Im new to typescript and am stumbling on this issue. I've searched around for a while but have not been able to find an answer.

What I want to do is define a properly typed sorting function which takes two arguments; an array of objects and a property of that object (as a string) on which to sort (using the JS myArray.sort() method).

Each object has a structure of InterfaceObject defined as

```
interface InterfaceObject {
    prop1: string
    prop2: number
    prop3: SomeEnum
}
```

The sorting function:

```
function sortBy(array: InterfaceObject[], sortKey: keyof InterfaceObject) {
    array.sort((a,b) => b[sortKey] - a[sortKey]
}
```

Although this works, TS is not happy because the .sort() method requires the types 'any', 'number' or 'bigint', and it cannot tell what type a property of InterfaceObject holds.

ideal situation:

```
sortBy(array, 'prop2') // okay: as its a number and key of InterfaceObject
sortBy(array, 'prop1') // error: as its not a number
sortBy(array, 'nonExistentProperty') // error: as its not a key of InterfaceObject
```

Im thinking using generics would help here, but I dont know to approach them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with generics.

```
function sortBy<
  T extends Record<K, number>, 
  K extends string
>(array: T[], sortKey: K) {
    array.sort((a, b) => b[sortKey] - a[sortKey])
}
```

We can define two generic types `T` and `K` where `T` is the type of the elements of the array we pass to the function. `T` is constrained to have a property `K` which is of type `number` and `K` is constrained to be of type `string`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAygeyiAopWBvYMYCICCuwAvsMAJZgAuIATgGYCGAxiDAJLV1OsDyARgCsQzKjCw4cAB1oIpARgBcMAM5ValAObZJMuQCZl6fnR3TZUgMzLEyNNBJlg9CGFHkEYVQlpUAQgCeADw6ACowIAAeNGAAJiowAEoiPrFBANIANDDGdAB82TrpEdHg8arqWsB5ABSMtLSMAcqhANoAutkqPlTpIM0w6QCU4mYw9Y0BAHTdvjV12fwjALx5MPyts7397TAAtOObPX0B7UOOwMyeauMNTcqcNAwsIALCoh0wyzAdZFuBdTuAWyAHI9FJ9CCRgB6aEwBAAa3u4wS5CoCUYOWgJlo4ziMAR-Xh9A4XGefCEIiowH%20AUBk1B4PkUJgsIiDR8ykYqPROQQYkxuVoNJ6AImTVBYE8KEi5DU4CoAAULHQqAEWWy6LJaFyeQkpQKCUSECTHtwXm8qUA)

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for. I had tried extending a generic as a solution, just was extending the wrong things xD

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an arithmetic operation simply compare the values and return -1, 0, or 1 instead.

```js
function sortBy(array: InterfaceObject[], sortKey: keyof InterfaceObject) {
  array.sort((a, b) => b[sortKey] < a[sortKey]
    ? -1
    : b[sortKey] > a[sortKey]
      ? 1
      : 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although this works, it does not generate any TS errors when the property is not a number type.

Comment: Oh, I got it the opposite of the "ideal situation". It works for every comparable and sorts it.